# Get all with distinct user id and order by total score

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table where same users id multiple times, in table also column of score 
now I want to get all record from table total score of distinct user order by total score with distinct user id

I am trying to implement following query but not working

```
select contId,answer,question,ContributorsId,sum(TotalScore) TotalScore 
from top_contributors 
group by ContributorsId 
order by TotalScore DESC
```

please note that contid is primary key(auto increment) and ContributorsId is userid Thanks

Comment: Better to include sample data, table definition and expected output in your question

Comment: i understand thanks

Comment: Hashaam, your requirement to see all the fields for each aggregated contributor makes no sense, because it isn't clear _which_ record out of the group should be providing that information.  Please edit your question and show us sample input and output data.

Comment: please check question

Comment: @Hashaam If you understand, why don't you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a simple aggregate query

```
select contributorId,sum(score) totalscore 
from top_contributors 
group by contributorId
order by totalscore
```

Comment: If you want all the columns add in select list and in group by clause

Comment: Actually, if `contributorId` is the primary key of the `top_contributors` table, then it should be possible to add _any_ columns to the select list +1.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I agree with your point but according to newer version the query may be considered as invalid if there exists any non aggregated column in select list

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Actually the ANSI standard allows for this (rats I don't have a reference), but only when grouping by the primary key.  If not, then what you said is correct.

Comment: `select id,month,year,contributorId,sum(score) totalscore from top_contributors  group by contributorId order by totalscore` but give me error

Comment: how to get all column , please come to know that contributorId is not primary key ,

Comment: @Hashaam The other columns will not be the same for all rows with the same `contributorsId`. Which row should it get those columns from?

Comment: @Hashaam again i will repeat the same can you include sample data, table definition and expected output in your question, It would be good if you can use any online tool like http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://rextester.com/ for your schema and data

Answer (score 1):

```
select tc.contributorId, sum(score) as totalscore
from top_contributors tc
group by contributorId
order by totalscore
```

I am sure it should work.